# Is it possible for an SFDC Apex unit test to parse a debug log?

Tags: unit-testing, debugging, salesforce, integration-testing, apex-code

I'm currently playing around with SFDC-Http Integration and the new Mock server functionality.

In the Apex code which I am testing, I have this branch condition:

```
if (response.getStatusCode() != 200) { debugResponse (response); }
        else { update (processInvoiceList(invoiceIdList, response)); }
```

... and I can thoroughly test what happens if the status code is 200.

However, if the status code is not 200, the code executed is simply this:

```
 /**
 * Write debugging information
 * @param HttpResponse response : Http response (e.g., from sendJsonToRemoteService())
 * @return None
 **/
private static void debugResponse (HttpResponse response)
{
    System.debug(                                                   
                LoggingLevel.ERROR , 
                '!!!!! Error from ' + request.getEndpoint() + ' : ' + response.getStatusCode() + ' ' + response.getStatus()
                ); 
}
```

This being the case, as the code currently stands, the only changes made to the system to check for would be to check the debug log.

I realize I could refactor my source to expose the HttpResponse (i.e. make it a public class variable), but aside from testing there is no need to expose it, so I don't want to if I don't need to.

So, instead, I'd like my unit test to parse the error log for the error message.

Is this possible?

If so, how?

Comment: Great question! If you don't get a suitable response, I would suggest reposting this at salesforce.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Daniel Blackhall: Good idea!  Done: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/14292/is-it-possible-for-an-sfdc-apex-unit-test-to-parse-a-debug-log